# manipulating position of div on hover

Tags: html, css

I have two separate divs which I would like to overlap each other on their hover states. The yellow div is doing this, but I'm having trouble with the blue div. As you can see it's expanding to the right by default. Is there anyway to force it to the left instead of growing its container.

This is a simplified example of what I'm working with so unfortunately I'm 99% sure the relative positioning on .work-wrapper has to say.

https://jsfiddle.net/04vjcfLe/5/

I've tried max-width on the container and a few other tricks but am now lost.

```
.work-container {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}

.work-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 49%;
    transition: all ease 0.8s;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```css
.work-container {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.work-1, .work-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  width: 50%;
 transition: all ease 0.8s;
}

.work-1:hover, .work-2:hover {
  width: 100%;
 transition: all ease 0.8s;
}

.work-1:hover + .work-2 {
  width: 0%;
 transition: all ease 0.8s;
}

.work-1 {
 background-color: #FEF102;
  left: 0;
}

.work-2 {
 background-color: #4B3E7F;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-container">
  <div class="work-1"></div>
  <div class="work-2"></div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**

In this solution, there's no absolute or relative positioning, so that you're free to set them however you want them.

```css
.work-container {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100px;
}

.work-1, .work-2 {
  width: 50%;
  transition: all ease 0.8s;
}

.work-container .work-1:hover, .work-container .work-2:hover {
  width: 100%  !important;
  transition: all ease 0.8s;
}

.work-container:hover .work-1 {
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease 0.8s;
}

.work-container .work-1:hover + .work-2 {
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease 0.8s;
}

.work-1 {
 background-color: #FEF102;
  left: 0;
}

.work-2 {
 background-color: #4B3E7F;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-container">
  <div class="work-1"></div>
  <div class="work-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but it needs to be the main boxes need to be relative positioning because I have absolute divs inside them.

Comment: @MaxPower then see the second solution. You should be able to devise the exact solution you want from there.

Comment: Thanks dude. You answered my question, still having an issue implementing this into my project but hopefully I can work it out.

Comment: @MaxPower I don't know what your real problem is but in many cases it's useful to set overflow:hidden to elements whose size change in a transition so that the content doesn't break. This usually involves sub-containers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I ending up using left: -100% on hover as well as z-index. As Ram said z-index isn't transition-able but this may have to do. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:right` to class work-2 and `z-index:6` to .w-2:hover .work-2

```css
.work-container {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.work-wrapper {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
  width: 49%;
 transition: all ease 0.8s;
}

.work-1, .work-2 {
 transition: all ease 0.8s;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.work-1 {
 background-color: #FEF102;
 z-index: 5;
}

.work-2 {
 background-color: #4B3E7F;
    float:right;
}

.w-1:hover .work-1 {
 width: 202%;
  float:left;
}

.w-2:hover .work-2 {
 width: 202%;
  z-index:6;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-container">
 <div class="work-wrapper w-1">
  <div class="work-1"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="work-wrapper w-2">
  <div class="work-2"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that due to z-indexing being no transitionnable, there's a discontinuity when you stop hovering.

Comment: Works well but had to give the answer to Deny. +1 though :)